# Option Value of Javascript file returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have following problem. I want that the user picks an option of a select panel. Then after he clicks the button he is taken to another file where the value of his choice is put in a variable and then displayed. It is important that its opened in a new file. But with my code the variable returns undefined. Here is my Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  a=$("#mySelect").val();
  switch(a){
    case "Orange":
    var b="Orange";
    return b;
    case "Apple":
    var b="Apple";
    return b;
    case "Pineapple":
    var b="Pineapple";
    return b;
    case "Banana":
    var b="Banana";
    return "Banana";
}
}
var test=myFunction();
$("button").on("click",blub);
function blub(){
  window.open(
"/Users/Adrian/Desktop/jj.html",
'_blank' 
);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <select id="mySelect">
   <option value="Apple">
Apple
   </option>
   <option value="Orange">
Orange
   </option>
   <option value="Pineapple">
Pineapple
   </option>
   <option value="Banana">
Banana
   </option>
  </select>
  <p class="bla">
   Click the button to select the option element with index "2".
  </p>
  <p>
   <b>
Note:
   </b>
   The index starts at 0.
  </p>
  <button>
   Try it
  </button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="j.js">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf-8" src="jj.js">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(".bla").html(test);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="bla"></p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="j.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jj.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `myFunction` would do the same job when re-written as: `function myFunction() { return $("#mySelect").val(); }`

Comment: @Adkoda In the new file also you are loading j.js and jj.js, if the javascript code in your code snippet is in any of the above file, then it will be agian executed, that way it will create a new instance of "test". Better option is store whatever needed to be displayed in new file  at localstorage or sessionstoarge level/

Comment: Or pass the value as a url parameter and read if in the other file from the url

Comment: @Asutosh thank you for your fast respond. How would this file look like? And do I need any other programming language like PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only get the value of the select once the button is clicked, not on page load. Then, you can set it in the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) so that the other page can access it.

JavaScript for first page:

```
$("button").on("click", blub);

function blub() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("value", $('#mySelect').val());
    window.open(
        "/Users/Adrian/Desktop/jj.html",
        '_blank'
    );
}
```

JavaScript for the second page:

```
$(".bla").text(sessionStorage.getItem('value'));
```